# Does there exist an entire function such that f(z+i) = f(z)+1, f(z+1) = f(z)+i, for all z?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

This problem seems to be a variant of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36817/how-to-prove-that-if-fz-is-entire-and-fzi-fz-fz1-fz-then-fz) one, but the same argument doesn't hold here since we can't say that $f$ is determined by its values in the unit square.

I tried to reduce the problem to the original one by defining $g(z)=f(z)+iz$, which doesn't work since it gives $g(z+i)=g(z)$, $g(z+1)=g(z)+2i$.
Any clues on how to approach this?

Comment: Doesn't this make $f'$ entire and doubly periodic, hence, constant?

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson, that solved it.

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer following a clue suggested by @GerryMyerson.

Let $f$ be an entire function as described in the question. Its derivative $g$ is also an entire function. For $g$ we have that $g(z+i)=g(z)$, $g(z+1)=g(z)$. Using the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36817/how-to-prove-that-if-fz-is-entire-and-fzi-fz-fz1-fz-then-fz) we have that g is constant, which means $f$ is a linear function. Hence, $f(z)=az+b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb C$.

Using the original constraints for $f$, we get:
$az+ai+b=a(z+i)+b = f(z+i) = f(z)+1 = az+b+1 => ai=1 =>a=-i$
$az+a+b=a(z+1)+b = f(z+1) = f(z)+i = az+b+i => a=i$

Which gives $i=-i$, a contradiction.